# I am getting null pointer exception when i get the data from xml document using web service

Tags: java

```
String name= "Nsss";
String resulturl ="http://ssss/res/get?sid="+name+"";



DocumentBuilder db = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
InputSource is = new InputSource();
is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(resulturl));
Document doc = db.parse(resulturl);
System.out.println("sssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss"+doc.getDoctype().getTextContent());
```

I am getting this exception.

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at com.controller.StudentsResultsController.main(ResultsController.java:130)

Comment: are you sure that `doc` or `doc.getDoctype()` is not null

Comment: Which line is line 130?

Comment: You have got to check out what's happening at `StudentsResultsController.java:130`. At least this should be the entry point of your investigation.

Comment: ya iam getting in the parse line only..before i used name in url directly .that time i got  results.but now i used parameter in that .

Comment: 130 line ::doc.getDoctype().getcontext();                               it not parsing when i use name dynamicly.before i used name directly in url that time i got result

Comment: yes .before i m using name in url.that time it works.but after that i changed "name" dynamically.now iam getting exception while parsing the url

Comment: String name= "Nsss";
String resulturl ="http://ssss/res/get?sid="+name+"";



DocumentBuilder db = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
InputSource is = new InputSource();
is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(resulturl));
Document doc = db.parse(resulturl);

Comment: Chances are the `DocType` object has not been instanciated.

Comment: i just took that name from url and stored in string .after that i used that name in url .nothing i changed in that url

Answer (score 0):

You should check to see what the `resulturl` variable is before you use it, but the other thing you need to address is: You are not using the `InputSource` at all. The following is likely to work better than what you have:

```
InputSource is = new InputSource();
is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(resulturl));
Document doc = db.parse(is);
```

**EDIT**

The Fatal Error is caused by the following:

> StringReader(resulturl) takes a string argument that must be XML, not a filename or a URL. The parser is reading the value of the string variable, resulturl, and failing immediately because an XML document may not begin with an h character.

Try changing the above to:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();          
Document doc = dBuilder.parse(new InputSource(resulturl));
```

Comment: [Fatal Error] :1:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
Exception in thread "main" org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.                                i am getting exception like this  ..when i use ur code

Comment: resulturl is working fine i changed some other names also in browser it works fine .but when i pass the value dynamically iam getting exception.

Comment: i am getting same exception . peter

Comment: The same exception? SAXParseException?

Comment: same exception java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Ok - when you debug your code, what value does *resulturl* have just before the program crashes? And don't just repeat what you wrote above. You need to actually check the value during run-time. If *resulturl* has a valid value, then check the value of *doc*, and finally, the value of *doc.getDocType()*. One of those has to be `null`, because you aren't using InputSource.

Comment: System.out.println("result urlllllllllllllllllllllllllll"+resulturl);
 
  
   System.out.println("---------------"+name);
   i am getting exact values in sysout..after that im parsing that url .

Comment: Ok - that means that getDoctype() is returning null. Also... you are trying to get the text content from a potential document type? I am no Java expert, but that just seems wrong (even if the type wasn't null).

Comment: ok peter thank you for the responce.. i tried with out doc type.i am getting only element values .now its working